# Refactor setState to have a function inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I need help refactoring my setState function.

I have this state:

```
state = {
    orderForm: {
        name: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Your Name'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        street: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Street'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        zipCode: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'ZIP Code'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 5,
                maxLength: 5
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        country: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Country'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        email: {
            elementType: 'input',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'email',
                placeholder: 'Your E-Mail'
            },
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        deliveryMethod: {
            elementType: 'select',
            elementConfig: {
                options: [
                    {value: 'fastest', displayValue: 'Fastest'},
                    {value: 'cheapest', displayValue: 'Cheapest'}
                ]
            },
            value: '',
            valid: true
        }
    },
    formIsValid: false,
    loading: false
}
```

And this code

:

```
inputChangedHandler = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
    const updatedOrderForm = {
        ...this.state.orderForm
    };
    const updatedFormElement = { 
        ...updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier]
    };
    updatedFormElement.value = event.target.value;
    updatedFormElement.valid = this.checkValidity(updatedFormElement.value, updatedFormElement.validation);
    updatedFormElement.touched = true;
    updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier] = updatedFormElement;

    let formIsValid = true;
    for (let inputIdentifier in updatedOrderForm) {
        formIsValid = updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier].valid && formIsValid;
    }
    this.setState({orderForm: updatedOrderForm, formIsValid: formIsValid});
}
```

Please, help me refactor the function in a way that uses a function inside of a setState.

As far as I know, using it like this is not good, because setState is asynchronous and when it is based on the previous state, a function should be used inside of setState.

Comment: I honestly see no problem in the function. You copy information from the state to local variables, run some codes on them, and then update the state.
"based on the previous state, a function should be used inside of setState".. Not sure why, actually.. Probably all React App are based on function that are based on "previus" state, which will lead to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `setState` in React is asynchronous operation. Your concern is valid.

Please have a look at the updated code for your handler event.

```
inputChangedHandler = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updatedOrderForm = {
                ...prevState.orderForm,
            };
            const updatedFormElement = {
                ...updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier],
            };
            updatedFormElement.value = event.target.value;
            updatedFormElement.valid = this.checkValidity(updatedFormElement.value, updatedFormElement.validation);
            updatedFormElement.touched = true;
            updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier] = updatedFormElement;

            let formIsValid = true;
            for (let inputIdentifier in updatedOrderForm) {
                formIsValid = updatedOrderForm[inputIdentifier].valid && formIsValid;
            }

            return { orderForm: updatedOrderForm, formIsValid: formIsValid };
        });
    };
```

Here, we pass setState a function as an argument whose argument is previous state and then return a new state object after applying the business logic.

Hope this helps.